# How to extract event from one source only Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I have to build a program for the employees of my company to declare days of work, vacation, days of illness etc.. My idea was to use fullcalendar drag and drop function to make something nice. Only on Month view, you drag the event "Work" and put it to the days you worked, as simple as that.

What i try to do, is to extract the event displayed to put them in the database, i tried using :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
```

but i also get the event from my googlecalendar used to display public holidays in background event.

In other words, I have two types of events, the ones I drag and drop, and the ones put there by googlecalendar on backgroundEvents.

Simply put, how can I filter the event I extract to ignore those from googlecalendar? So I put in an array all the event from the calendar, but i don't want those from google.

If possible, i'd be really grateful for any hint on the next step, putting those events in the data base.

What is the solution to extract only the event I added by hand?

Comment: Your question is too broad.  Please ask one specific question at a time.

Comment: Let's see this differently : 

I have two types of events, the ones I drag and drop, and the ones put there by googlecalendar on backgroundEvents.

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');

Put in an array all the event from the calendar but i don't want thoses from google. 
What is the solution to extract only the event I added by hand.  Is it clear enough ?

Comment: @RohitGupta The question is not too broad because he is asking for a specific feature in a specific library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, i finally got this thanks to a mate at the office. Leaving the answer here just in case:

googlecalendars events and manually added events don't have the same attributs, the googlecalendars ones have 'source' and 'url' attribut that the others don't have.

What you want to do is to get all the event, loop through your array with and select only thoses who doesn't have the source attribut. :

```
function send(){
        var  cal_events = ''
       data= $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');

       for (var key in data) {
            var event = data[key];

            if (typeof(event.source) == 'undefined'){
                 //Your stuff
                    }

                });
            }
        }
    }
```

That way you can act only on the events without the 'source' attribut.

Thanks anyway. Robin

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to the [clientEvents](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) function like this:

```
var data = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents',function(event){
    return !(event.source && event.source.googleCalendarId);
});
```

Comment: Nice ! With a little if (true) {ajax} else {nothing} it should be perfect. Thanks ! 

Edit :Ok I may have spoken too fast, The "!event.source" still returns all the event by saying if the condition is true so I amnot sure it is working properly.

Comment: I wrote this because I saw `typeof(event.source) == 'undefined'` in your answer. I assumed that all your manually added events did not have the `source` property.

Comment: You assumed right, probleme is, instead of just returning the event without source, it returns every event and state if they own the source property.

Comment: Yeah that's weird. I've edited my post, hope it helps.

Comment: It does the same problem. I tried to alert() it and for 2 google events and 1 custom i got false - false - true.  Don't mind it, even though it may be quite ugly i got what i needed from my previous answer.  It still intrigue me though.

Comment: @Robin Ok, glad you resolved your issue anyway :) I thought it could be nicer